# chaining tweens in paperjs

Tags: javascript, paperjs, tween

I am trying to chain tweens in paperjs but for some reason the `start()` function of `tween` is not working inside `then()` function of another tween. If I call the `start()` function outside, it works tho. The only way to maybe navigate this problem is if I define the tween inside `then()` function but that seems to me like I am chaining wrong, how `.then()` can be chained wrong with promises.

```
var size = new Size(605, 605);
var back = new Path.Rectangle(view.center-size/2, size);
back.fillColor = 'black';

project.currentStyle = {
    strokeColor: 'white',
    strokeWidth: 4,
    strokeCap: 'round'
}

var ln = 150;
var group = new Group();
var line1 = new Path.Line(
    {x: view.center.x + ln/2, y: view.center.y - ln},
    {x: view.center.x + ln/2, y: view.center.y - ln*2/3});
group.addChild(line1);

var lineh1 = new Path.Line(
    {x: view.center.x + ln/2, y: view.center.y - ln*2/3},
    {x: view.center.x - ln/3, y: view.center.y - ln*2/3});
var arc1 = new Path.Arc(
    {x: view.center.x - ln/3, y: view.center.y - ln*2/3},
    {x: view.center.x - ln/3 - ln/4-ln/12, y: view.center.y - ln*1/3},
    {x: view.center.x - ln/3, y: view.center.y });
var ref1 = {x: view.center.x + ln/4, y: view.center.y};
var ref2 = {x: view.center.x + ln/2 + ln/4, y: view.center.y - ln/8};
var lineh2 = new Path.Line(
    {x: view.center.x - ln/3, y: view.center.y},
    {x: view.center.x + ln/4, y: view.center.y});
var arc2 = new Path.Arc(
    {x: view.center.x + ln/4, y: view.center.y},
    {x: view.center.x + ln/4 + ln/4+ln/4, y: view.center.y + ln/2},
    {x: view.center.x + ln/4, y: view.center.y + ln});
var lineh3 = new Path.Line(
    {x: view.center.x + ln/4, y: view.center.y + ln},
    {x: view.center.x - ln/3 - ln/4, y: view.center.y + ln})
group.addChildren([lineh1, arc1, lineh2, arc2, lineh3]);    
// group.scale(0.8, 1);
// var groupC = group.clone().scale(-1, 1);
// var arc1C = arc1.clone().scale(-1, 1, view.center);
// var arc2C = arc2.clone().scale(-1, 1, view.center);
var arc1C = arc1.clone();
var arc2C = arc2.clone();
arc1C.visible = false;
arc2C.visible = false;

// arc1C.scale(1.2, -1.5, arc1C.lastSegment.point);
// arc2C.scale(0.8, -0.67, arc2C.firstSegment.point);


// animations
var tspan = 4000;
var amp = 0.1;


var t1a1 = arc1C.tween(
    {'firstSegment.point': arc2.lastSegment.point,
    'firstSegment.handleOut': arc2.lastSegment.handleIn,
    'lastSegment.point': arc2.firstSegment.point,
    'lastSegment.handleIn': arc2.firstSegment.handleOut,
    'segments[1].point': arc2.segments[1].point,
    'segments[1].handleIn': arc2.segments[1].handleIn*-1,
    'segments[1].handleOut': arc2.segments[1].handleOut*-1
    },
    {   
        duration: tspan,
        start: false,
    });
var t1a2 = arc2C.tween(
    {'lastSegment.point': arc1.firstSegment.point, 
    'lastSegment.handleIn': arc1.firstSegment.handleOut,
    'firstSegment.point': arc1.lastSegment.point,
    'firstSegment.handleOut': arc1.lastSegment.handleIn,
    'segments[1].point': arc1.segments[1].point,  
    'segments[1].handleIn': arc1.segments[1].handleIn*-1,
    'segments[1].handleOut': arc1.segments[1].handleOut*-1
    },
    {   
        duration: tspan,
        start: false,
    });

// t1a1.start();

var t1 = arc2.tween(tspan)
t1.onUpdate = function(event) {
    var times = tspan/1000 * 61;
    var t = event.factor*times/6;
    var f = Math.sin(t);
    twerk(t, f);
}
t1.then(function() {
    console.log('hello');
    arc1C.visible = true;
    arc2C.visible = true;
    arc1C.scale(-1, 1, view.center);
    arc2C.scale(-1, 1, view.center);
    t1a1.start();
    t1a2.start();
})

function twerk(t, f) {
    arc2.shear(0, -Math.sin(t*2)*0.06, arc2.firstSegment.point);
    arc1.scale(1 + f*0.02, 1)
    arc2C.shear(0, Math.sin(t*2)*0.06, arc2C.firstSegment.point);
    arc1C.scale(1 + f*0.02, 1)
}


var lineTop = new Path.Line(
            {x: view.center.x - ln + ln/8, y: view.center.y - ln},
            {x: view.center.x + ln - ln/8, y: view.center.y - ln}
            )
lineTop.style = {
    strokeColor: '#fae0e4',
    strokeWidth: 15,
    strokeCap: 'butt'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i've faced the same trouble when started to use Tween.
This is happening because when you create Tween, it's bound to current state of object, so when object changes during animation, all previously created tweens not working.

My solution was to create tween fabric with callback

It looks like this:

```
function getTween(object, tweenDescr, tweenOptions){
    // DEFAULTS
    tweenOptions = tweenOptions || { duration: 2000, start: false };
    return function(callback){
        tw = object.tweenTo(tweenDescr, tweenOptions);
        tw.start();
        tw.then(function(){
            callback && callback();
        })
    }
}
```

And this is how i use it:

```
var circle = new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center,
    radius: 40,
    fillColor: 'blue'
});

var one = getTween(circle, {fillColor: 'red'});
var two = getTween(circle, {fillColor: 'green'});
var three = getTween(circle, {fillColor: 'blue'});

one(function(){
    two(function(){
        three();
    });
});
```

If you want to avoid "callback hell", you can use [async.js](https://caolan.github.io/) with its eachSeries or similar utilities

Usage will be like:

```
async.eachSeries([one,two,three], function(tweenOperation, callback) {
    tweenOperation(callback);
}, function(err) {
    console.log('all done');
});
```

[Here's my sketch with callback-hell](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.15/S/jVLLboMwEPyVFYfEkRBCVU9EPaX3VmpudQ/GbAqNu0bGhAPh32sb54GqSuXkmd3ZmV0xJiS+MSmStyNaWSdpInXl8UkYkI2RCuEJCAd4FbbOdoFhIydwn0SyaAo4NThkM0jnihFV03cFPOaRODRK7bTSrntdqh7XnKbNlhMnb6TJu7QGW2FwPyASm71TGO+VBqt1kHmRHfS/RJ/Gle5ktcP/EoacMaVLyA49SdtoYpu4v0vwmwwF78G80qMwIs65tC/tdfmF0qZuoEPP2EkT3y+tb+5uhjfOrbCA5zOMUPVGeFjAQ57nKXRWGFvAQagOYYp5DNreEFyTS6FUKeTRu3A7+7jpc6gsmOw1+zPb9qbKgh9bULZ2Cy6uxO1cvPjCanV932mnTTyfOx4n92eWBsWx1Q3ZLineP6Yf)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution like so

```
Promise.resolve()
.then(() => jump(chair, -ln/4, ln/8, 'hor', tspan)) 
.then(() => squish(leftArc, leftLine.firstSegment.point, {x: 1,y: -1}, tspan/2))
.then(() => squish(leftArc, leftLine.firstSegment.point, {x: -1,y: 1}, tspan/2))
.catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

Each of these functions `jump` and `squish` etc return a tween object